# How can i run 2 function at the same time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

So basically, i am coding Sea Quest, and i need to make the shark and the diver moove at the sime time, except i've been using Set Interval for both of the function which work perfectely fine when they are alone

Shark function :

```
function initAlien() {
    if (intervalId) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    const alienY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 3 + 1) + 3); // generate a random row for the aliens (limited to rows 3-10)
    var RandVersDroite = Math.round(Math.random())
    posAlienY = alienY;
    if(RandVersDroite == 0)
    {
        vaVersLaDroite = false;
        posAlienX = 19
        plateau[posAlienY][posAlienX].style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/aliengauche.png')";
    }
    else
    {
        vaVersLaDroite = true;
        posAlienX = 0;
        plateau[posAlienY][posAlienX].style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/alien.png')";
    }
    
    
    
    plateau[posAlienY][posAlienX].name = "alien";
    intervalId = setInterval(parcoursGrille, 200);
}
```

Diver function :

```
function initPlongeur() {
    if (intervalId) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    const PlongeurY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 3 + 1) + 3); // generate a random row for the  Plongeurs (limited to rows 3-10)
    var NageurVersDroite = Math.round(Math.random())
    posPlongeurY =  PlongeurY;
    if(NageurVersDroite == 0)
    {
        NageurVersLaDroite = false;
        posPlongeurX = 19
        plateau[posPlongeurY][posPlongeurX].style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/nadador2.png')";
    }
    else
    {
        NageurVersLaDroite = true;
        posPlongeurX = 0;
        plateau[posPlongeurY][posPlongeurX].style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/nadador2.png')";
    }
    
    
    
    plateau[posPlongeurY][posPlongeurX].name = " Plongeur";
    intervalId = setInterval(parcoursGrillePlongeur, 200);
}
```

And then, i call them like this in another Js file :

```
initAlien();
initPlongeur();
```

I want the shark and the diver to work both at the same time but it only make the last one moove (if initAlien(); is after initPlongeur(); then the shark is mooving but not the diver

I tried looking for asynchronous function, or changed my code a little but it won't work

Comment: Literally "_run 2 function at the same time in Javascript_" is not possible. Use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and call both of your functions in the callback.

Comment: Offtopic: When you want to code a game, you should use a game engine instead like three, phaser, babylon.

Comment: So i can only make one work at the same time ?

Comment: Or i just could combine the two function

Comment: Yes, JS has only a single thread to run the scripts. The same thread is used to also render the view in the browser. You don't need to combine the functions, just call them separately.

Comment: But i need them to work at the same time so i can't just do this right ?

Comment: I don't think your issue is with "parallel execution" to begin with here. (You can not have two _continuous_ functions run at the same time, but with setInterval here this is a different story.) Your `intervalId` variable is not local to each of those two functions - so when `initPlongeur` gets called, the first thing it does, is _clear_ the interval, that `initAlien` stored into the variable `intervalId`.

Comment: And that mixture between English and French variable names you got going on there, is quite ... _épouvantable_. Please decide on frog _or_ beef ;-)